# Status bar in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I cannot find a control for implementing a status bar. How can I do it manually?

Answer (score 25):

I think you're looking for the StatusStrip control. Here's [an article about it](http://www.visualcplusdotnet.com/visualcplusdotnet22f.html).

And here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229738.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it manually, here's what you will have to do:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip statusStrip2;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      this.statusStrip2 = new System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      this.statusStrip2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 251);
      this.statusStrip2.Name = "statusStrip2";
      this.statusStrip2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 22);
      this.statusStrip2.TabIndex = 0;
      this.statusStrip2.Text = "statusStrip2";
      this.Controls.Add(this.statusStrip2);

      this.PerformLayout();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to Dock to the bottom!

Comment: @Yadyn. A StatusStrip has its Dock property set to Bottom by default.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like the [StatusStrip](http://dotnetdud.blogspot.com/2009/01/simple-statusstrip-control-example.html) control?

Answer (score 1):

There is the `StatusStrip` control, found in the "Menus & Toolbars" category in the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

.NET does include a statusbar. You can find it under *Menu & Toolbar*. It's called StatusStrip.

Answer (score 0):

The control is called 'StatusStrip' and it is located in your toolbox.  If it isn't you can find it under the 'System.Windows.Forms" namespace.