# StatusStrip equivalent

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, devexpress

What is the [DevExpress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevExpress#Product_list) equivalent for [StatusStrip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.statusstrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

I need just a line which to shows me a sting - I don't need any ribboncontrols or something like this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An equivalent is the StatusBar from the XtraBars Suite.  When you drop the BarManager onto a form, it will create a couple of toolbars in the top of the form and the statusBar on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

There is an StatusStrip too in [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms). Please check Stack Overflow question *[Status bar in C# Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969755)*.

Comment: I need the devexpress equivalent of this control

Comment: Why does it have to be DevExpress?

Comment: If the rest of the form is written in DevExpress the chances are you want a consistent look and feel.